# navbar-fixed-top class creating an unwanted horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css

I am trying to ad a fixed top bar to a webpage using bootstrap navbar-fixed-top class. 
Unfortunately I get an overflow or extra horizontal scroll all the time. 
I am withing a platform called Teachable that uses what they call Liquid Blocks, basically blocks that allows me to add markup to their pages. 
This is my webpage: http://abriendo-tu-voz.teachable.com/p/abriendo-tu-voz-indefinido/
How to fix that horizontal scroll?

Comment: Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you already tried yourself to do this? This isn't a debugging service. Also, for us to be able to help,you need to include the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a clear outline of your specific coding-related issue directly in your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a quick fix. You should locate and fix the underlying problem.

CSS

```
:root {
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that already and the problem persists. I've spent hours and can't figure out what the problem is.